# How do I reduce the code complexity of this task?

Tags: java

Basically I have this task where I need to find the median of an array based on the sum of the elements to it's left and the elements to it's right.

If an array is:

> 1 2 3 4 5

The output here should be 4 , because the left sum is 6 and the right is 5.

This is the code that solves this task:

```java
    /**
     * This method calculates the smallest difference and returns it's index.
     *
     * @param array The array being targeted by the method.
     * @return The index of the smallest difference as an integer.
     */
    private static int findSmallestDifference(int[] array) {
        if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        int smallestDifferenceIndex = 0;
        int currentDifference = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            int currentElement = Math.abs(array[i]);
            if (currentElement < currentDifference) {
                smallestDifferenceIndex = i;
                currentDifference = currentElement;
          } else if (currentElement == currentDifference
              && array[i] > 0
              && array[smallestDifferenceIndex] < 0) {
                  smallestDifferenceIndex = i;
          }
        }
        return smallestDifferenceIndex + 1;
    }
```

```java
    /**
     * This method calculates the left and the right sum of the array.
     *
     * @param array The array being targeted by the method.
     * @return The median of the array as an integer.
     */
    public static int getMedian(int[] array) {
        if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        int[] prefix = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
        int[] suffix = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
        int[] difference = new int[array.length];

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            prefix[i] = prefix[i] + prefix[i - 1];
        }

        for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            suffix[i - 1] = suffix[i] + suffix[i - 1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            difference[i] = Math.abs(prefix[i] - suffix[i]);
        }
        return findSmallestDifference(difference);
    }
```

My question is how can I simplify this solution?

Comment: Define “simplify”. Are you looking to reduce LOC, time complexity or what? What problems do you see with the existing solution?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could simplify the task of >reading< your code .... by using proper indentation.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar By simplify I mean the solution itself. For example I've been told that this task's best solution is by two loops , but I can't think of a way to implement it like that.

Comment: @StephenC Sorry about that , I format my code using google-java-formatter and when I paste it here it gets messy.

Answer (score 2):

```java
public static int findMedian(int[] arr) {
    int[] leftSum = new int[arr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        leftSum[i] = i == 0 ? arr[i] : leftSum[i - 1] + arr[i];

    int rightSum = 0;
    int minDif = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int median = 0;

    for (int i = arr.length - 2; i - 1 >= 0; i--) {
        rightSum += arr[i + 1];
        int dif = Math.abs(leftSum[i - 1] - rightSum);

        if (dif < minDif) {
            median = arr[i];
            minDif = dif;
        }
    }

    return median;
}
```

Comment: Perfect complexity; better answer. One thing: in 1 2 3 4 5 the left sum 6 is of 1 2 3, and the middle 4, and the right sum 5.  For this definition of mean, `rightSum += ...` must be done later.

Comment: Thank you @JoopEggen. I appreciate your message.

Comment: What does res stand for in this code?

Comment: `res = arr[i];` renamed it to `median = arr[i]`

Comment: But here I need the index of the element , not the element itself.

Comment: No problem, do retrieve `i` instead.

Answer (score 1):

- (Name `prefix` and `suffix` simply `leftSum` and `rightSum`.)
- `differences` does not need to be kept in an array, but the smallest difference can be found dynamically. If array is sorted, vou could have interpolated the smallest difference.
- `Arrays.copy` is redundant; maybe saves a line of code. `new int[array.length]` and a walking `int sum = 0;` would do too.

---

There is a problem in the calculating of the smallest difference

```
if (array == null) {
    return -1;
}
int smallestDifferenceIndex = -1;
int currentDifference = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    int left = i <= 0 ? 0 : prefix[i - 1];
    int right = i >= array.length - 1 ? 0 : suffix[i + 1];
    int currentElement = Math.abs(left - right);
    if (currentElement <= currentDifference) {
        smallestDifferenceIndex = i;
        currentDifference = currentElement;
    }
}
return smallestDifferenceIndex;
```

*By the way. Java as one successor of C++ wanted less nesting of { }, and took the convention of 4 spaces for an indentation.*

Comment: That's the thing that when I try to find the difference without using an array it doesn't work for some cases , for example the array I showed doesn't return the correct output because the calculations for the smallest difference become incorrect without the usage of a specific array to hold the values of the differences.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (returning the index): start at the ends and *walk inward*, from the side where expected difference is smaller:

```java
private static final int find(int... array) {
    var left = 0;
    var right = array.length-1;
    var sumL = 0;
    var sumR = 0;
    while (left < right) {
        var numL = array[left];
        var numR = array[right];
        if (abs((sumL+numL)-sumR) < abs(sumL-(sumR+numR))) {
            sumL += numL;
            left += 1;
        } else {
            sumR += numR;
            right -= 1;
        }
    }
    return right;
}
```

<sup>This is not expected to work if the array contains negative numbers (or zeros?)</sup>

---

EDIT:
if you need the index staring at `1` (not Java-like) then just add `1`:

```java
    . . .
    return right + 1;    // zero if the array is empty
}
```

---

BONUS:
Here my *brute force* solution used for testing<sup>*</sup>:

```java
private static int brute(int... array) {
    var result = -1;
    var min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var l = IntStream.range(0, i).map(j -> array[j]).sum();
        var r = IntStream.range(i+1, array.length).map(j -> array[j]).sum();
        var d = abs(l - r);
        if (d < min) {
            result = i;
            min = d;
        }
    }
    return result + 1;    // zero if array is empty
}
```

<sup>* after comments I also used code from question to check</sup>

Comment: It's a good solution but the thing I need to output specifically is the position of the median starting from 1 , check my code.

Comment: Well it is kind of because I used the logic you do before I wrote this piece of code and things didn't work out well and that's why I needed to change literally everything and now that it's done I am wondering how I can reduce the lines of code and basically have the same results.